# Replace specific values in a block of text leaving the text that is in between what I am searching for

Tags: php

I would like to convert this text `{unsubscribe|here.}` to `<a href="">here.</a>`.

I have already wrote the regular expression that picks up the different groups of matches.

In this case I know I can preg/str_replace the front and the end (`}`) of the text however this would be ineffective as i also would like to strip out another value like this which would be `{name}` for example.

This is the regular expression I have wrote. `/(\{unsubscribe\|)([a-z]*[^\}])(\})/`

Thanks,

Comment: and what is problem whith `preg_replace ('/(\{unsubscribe\|)([a-z]*[^\}])(\})/',"$2", $string) ?

Comment: I would like to leave the rest of the string behind as the `{unsubscribe|here.}` will be inserted in the body of an email. Is there a way to do the opposite of this and replace '$3' and then '$1' from the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = '{unsubscribe|{name} here.}';

function fix($m){
    return "<a href=''>".str_replace("{name}", "MY NAME", $m[1])."</a>";
}
print preg_replace_callback("/\{unsubscribe\|(.*)\}/", "fix", $str);
```

output:

```
<a href=''>MY NAME here.</a>
```

Comment: How would this work with, for example `Some text {unsubscribe|here.} some more text.` I have tried using your example by using the regular expression to capture all characters before and after and then in the function returning the text before and after the text we are replacing. Hopefully that makes sense to you.

Comment: I think this has done it `(.*)(\{unsubscribe\|)([a-z]*[^\}])(\})(.*)`

Comment: Thanks @waza123, your answer using the `preg_replace_callback` has been very helpful. This has allowed me to workout what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This will strip out the different parts of the string and replace where necessary.

I have worked out this solution based on @waza123 's answer.

```
$str = "Hi {name}, Some text {unsubscribe|here.} some more text.";

function fix($m){
    return $m[1] . str_replace($m[2], '<a href="">', $m[2]) . $m[3] . str_replace($m[4], '</a>', $m[4]) . $m[5];
}

$result = preg_replace_callback('/(.*)(\{unsubscribe\|)(.*[^\}])(\})(.*)/', 'fix', $str);

echo str_replace('{name}', 'Firstname Lastname', $result);
```

Output:

```
Hi Firstname Lastname, Some text <a href="">here.</a> some more text.
```